# Status code to be used when accessing a profile

Tags: php, http-headers

I have developed a PHP application with a myaccount area. Where myaccount will be the users personalized profile. And to access the myaccount area the users need to be logged-in. However if a user who is not logged in try to access the myaccount area I am redirecting them to the log-in page. At the moment I haven't add a custom header status code & chrome dev tools tell me that the status code 302 is being used. Is this ok for this type of purpose or do I need to use a different header like 301.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

302 means temporarly unavailable while 301 means permanent unavailable. So you see 302 is totally correct in that case.

Comment: When users try to access the myaccount without log-in I am redirecting them using php to the following URL :login-register?myaccount=1. So that I can capture that the user tried to access the account area without log-in. This gives a 302 redirect. If I refresh this link the header changes to status 200. Is this ok, or will it affect my SEO, specifying that two links direct to the same content.

Comment: That's ok. Status Code 200 means that the website could be loaded and no errors or redirects or anything else was done. For more information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

But what you can maybe do is using canonicalization: http://moz.com/learn/seo/canonicalization